# Unable to send data from HTML form to email using PHP mail()

Tags: php, email

Below is the piece of code I am using. Though I copy-paste the same syntax it is unable to send the full data to my mail. It just sends the blank data as shown in the screenshot of the email I get

[image]

My code is as follows.

```
<?php

$name=$_POST['name'];
$visitor_email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['comment'];

$email_from = 'noreply@example.com';

$email_subject = "New Form submission";

$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
                            "Here is the message:\n $message".


$to = "dummy@gmail.com";

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
                          
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
                          
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

I am checking it on the live hosting server of my domain.

Comment: What is expected result?  - is the textarea in the form named "comment"? Do you POST the form? Perhaps show the HTML since the send obviously works. The text in the email does not match the text in the PHP, could you please show the exact code and the exact HTML?

Comment: Sir the issue got resolved. Thank you for your words.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the entirety of your problem, but given that we cannot see your HTML, you may want to correct this line which has a period instead of a semicolon:

```
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
                            "Here is the message:\n $message".
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-inline" action="form/contact2.php" method="POST">
        <label for="email">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
        <label for="comment">Message</label>
        <input type="comment" id="comment" placeholder="Enter the message" name="comment">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

This is the HTML code